# Combine few arrays into one array in Lua - arg.n error

Tags: lua, lua-table, variadic-functions

I am trying to combine few arrays into a one singe array in Lua.
when I run this script I get error due to `arg.n = nil` value, shouldn't `arg.n` have the number of parameters sent into a function, need to loop over each

any advise ?

```
function array_concat(...)

-- Combine Multiple Arrays 
-- Usage: combined =  array_concat(T1, T2, T3 ....) 

    local t = {}


    -- [ERROR] 10:26:35: line 49: attempt to get length of global 'arg' (a nil value)
    print (arg.n) 
    -- arg.n is nil why ?


    for i = 1, arg.n do
        local array = arg[i]
        if (type(array) == "table") then
            for j = 1, #array do
                t[#t+1] = array[j]
            end
        else
            t[#t+1] = array
        end
    end

    return t
end


local Array1 = {1,2} 
local Array2 = {3,4} 


local Combine =  array_concat(Array1, Array2)   


for k, v in pairs( Combine ) do
   print(k, v)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code works in older version of Lua.

In Lua 5.2, `arg` isn't used to process variadic functions any more. Instead, it's a global variable that stores the command line arguments.

To process variadic functions, use `...` like this:

```
function foo(...)
  for k, v in ipairs{...} do
    --process
  end
end
```

The `n` field isn't used to get table length any more, either. Use `#t` to get the length of a sequence `t`.

Comment: Or even better: `for i = 1, select( '#', ... ) do local v = select( i, ... ) --[[ process ]] end`

Comment: To do it the old way you can say `local arg = table.pack(...)`.